# Register an event listener in Dropwizard

Tags: java, spring-boot, dropwizard, event-listener

Is there any possible way of registering listeners in Dropwizard equivalent to the following implementation in Spring Boot :

```
@EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class)
public void registerMessagingEvents() {
    registerListener1();
    registerListener2();        
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a `ServerLifecycleListener` to your Dropwizard `Environment`.

Typically this is done in your `Application` subclass' `run()` method.

For example:

```
@Override
public void run(YourApplicationConfiguration config, Environment environment) {
  environment.lifecycle().addServerLifecycleListener(new ServerLifecycleListener() {
    @Override
    public void serverStarted(Server server) {
      // do something
    }
  });

  // ... others
}
```

Although 'Jetty server ready' (which is what this Dropwizard lifecycle event indicates) isn't exactly the same as Spring Boot's `ApplicationReadyEvent` it is the equivalent hook as provided by Dropwizard and it might suffice for your needs.

More details [in the docs](http://www.dropwizard.io/1.2.2/docs/manual/internals.html).

Answer (score 1):

Another possible implementation may be using `environment.lifecycle().addLifeCycleListener`.

It is useful when you need to get access to some injected classes/instances.
For example:

```
//In the run method 
    Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(myModule); //existing code

    ...
    // somewhere in the end of the run method
    environment.lifecycle().addLifeCycleListener(
      new ServerLifecycleListener(injector.getInstance(MyService.class)));

//And then implement the listener ServerLifecycleListener class:
private static class ServerLifecycleListener implements LifeCycle.Listener {
private MyService myService;

ServerLifecycleListener(MyService myService) {
  this.myService = myService;
}

@Override
public void lifeCycleStarting(LifeCycle lifeCycle) {
}

@Override
public void lifeCycleStarted(LifeCycle lifeCycle) {
  myService.doSomething();
}

@Override
public void lifeCycleFailure(LifeCycle lifeCycle, Throwable throwable) {
}

@Override
public void lifeCycleStopping(LifeCycle lifeCycle) {
}

@Override
public void lifeCycleStopped(LifeCycle lifeCycle) {
}
```

}